# Running akka with runnable jar

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, akka

I'm trying to implement akka in java maven project with NetBeans. It runs fine when i run it from NetBeans but when I run the runnable jar from NetBeans, it generate error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages'
```

When I add log-received-message in the configuration, it ask for another configuration. This is the plugin that i used to generate the jar file.

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

And my dependency are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId> 
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.7</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

The configuration for akka is

```
akka10300{
akka{
    actor{provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"}
    remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
            hostname="127.0.0.1"
            port=10300
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a warning about running Akka from a "fat jar" at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html.  The issue is that there are multiple `reference.conf` configuration files, and the default behaviour of the Maven assembly or shade plugins is to overwrite earlier instances of the configuration file with later instances.

To fix this, the suggested approach is to use the Maven shade plugin to generate your executable jar and configure it to append all `resource.conf` files into a single file instead of overwriting.  The suggested Maven shade plugin configuration looks like:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.5</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>shade</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
    <shadedClassifierName>allinone</shadedClassifierName>
    <artifactSet>
     <includes>
      <include>*:*</include>
     </includes>
    </artifactSet>
    <transformers>
      <transformer
       implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
       <resource>reference.conf</resource>
      </transformer>
      <transformer
       implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
       <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>akka.Main</Main-Class>
       </manifestEntries>
      </transformer>
    </transformers>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Richard_Neish Thanks for the advise but when I used maven-assembly-plugin the reference.conf also generated at the root directory. I saved my akka configuration in other directory, it's not at application.conf. When I used maven-shade-plugin, the akka configuration wasn't found : no configuration setting found for key akka10300.

Comment: @Richard_Neish Hello, thanks mr richard. The akka plugin works. I think i made some mistake when configuring the akka before but it works now. Yeah thanks. :D

Comment: The only required/relevant part is using the transformer org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer