# sbt package configuration similar to IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I currently have a problem packaging my Scala application with sbt. Here's the situation.

Until now, in development phase, I used IntelliJ IDEA to compile and create jar artifacts that I could use to deploy. I'm using AKKA packages, and as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588402/8620481)

Akka team warns about using "fat jars" with Akka project, due to problem with configuration files. Because of this, I had to configure the production of my artifact with these configuration:

[image]

Selecting a single module, specifying a main class and the folder in which the program would place the MANIFEST.MF.

It all works well, the program generates the jar along with all the other jars, and I manage to start the jar in development.

While trying to automatize the process, I started using sbt, trying to generate artifacts the same way I did with IntelliJ IDEA, but I can't find any configuration that could mimic what IntelliJ's doing.

In particular, trying to run `sbt package` I even get this exception:

```
[error] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Is there any way to configure `sbt package` properly to behave the same way IntelliJ do?

PS: to corroborate my question, in the `src/main/scala` folder IntelliJ placed the file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, following the option I've selected to generate the artifact. The `build.sbt` doesn't have any particular option, I've only added the `libraryDependencies` that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the `reference.conf` problem in Akka, one solution is to append all these files when creating a fat jar.

The [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin allows this by specifying a `MergeStrategy`. For example:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "reference.conf"=> MergeStrategy.concat
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem with Akka, and I've managed to create a working fat jar with sbt assembly.