# Getting 'com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'ml.combust.mleap.spark'` error

Tags: apache-spark, mleap

I am trying to run the sample MLeap code example provided here: http://mleap-docs.combust.ml/spark/

All of the code works on my Spark cluster. However, whenever I to execute the following code snippet (again from the above link):

```
for(bundle <- managed(BundleFile("jar:file:/tmp/mleap-examples/simple-json.zip"))) {
  pipeline.writeBundle.format(SerializationFormat.Json).save(bundle)
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'ml.combust.mleap.spark'
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:145)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:172)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:258)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:264)
  at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:37)
  at ml.combust.bundle.BundleRegistry$.apply(BundleRegistry.scala:35)
  at ml.combust.bundle.BundleRegistry$.apply(BundleRegistry.scala:28)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.bundle.SparkBundleContext$.apply(SparkBundleContext.scala:21)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.bundle.SparkBundleContext$.defaultContext$lzycompute(SparkBundleContext.scala:15)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.bundle.SparkBundleContext$.defaultContext(SparkBundleContext.scala:15)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:87)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:86)
  at resource.AbstractManagedResource$$anonfun$5.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
  at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
  at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
  at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103)
  at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125)
  at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:88)
  at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.apply(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:26)
  at resource.AbstractManagedResource.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:50)
  at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.acquireAndGet(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:25)
  at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireAndGet(AbstractManagedResource.scala:50)
  at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.foreach(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:53)
  at resource.AbstractManagedResource.foreach(AbstractManagedResource.scala:50)
  ... 70 elided
```

I have also followed this similar problem link https://github.com/combust/mleap/issues/252 by adding the following in my maven pom.xml:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
</transformer>
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you try adding the transformer as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555174/running-akka-with-runnable-jar ? It worked for me, I can now see all the correct keys in the `reference.conf` file