# How to run properly an Akka application with a fat-JAR? (No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages')

Tags: java, maven, docker, akka

I have a simple Java application that uses Akka. I decided to dockerize it.

When i build and run the application everything seems fine but Akka throws this error:

```
< com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.remote.log-received-messages' >
```

This is the plugins section of the `pom.xml`:

```
...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>${project.build.directory}/dependency</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>it.uniroma3.initialization.Init</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>it.uniroma3.initialization.Init</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>       
    </plugins>
```

It seems like the libraries are correctly accessed but for some reason akka cannot start properly. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your problem do not seem to be a docker problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555174/running-akka-with-runnable-jar

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#when-using-jarjar-onejar-assembly-or-any-jar-bundler